# Evaluate solution from Laplace

Tags: matlab

The following variables were the solutions of a system of ODE by means of Laplace transform. The question is, how can I evaluate this as a function of `t`?

```
zs =

(426453367703541750000*sin(t))/422998807223231216101 - (126885219268500000*cos(t))/422998807223231216101 - (143127622539985885236418500000*sum(exp(r3*t)/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 - (898981813790513658018000000*sum((r3*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 - (35837444893658057322750000*sum((r3^2*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 + (10746289875507070500000*sum((r3^3*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101


zu =

(423526351592241700000*sin(t))/422998807223231216101 - (119538342000000*cos(t))/422998807223231216101 - (21856954524657863661418500000*sum(exp(r3*t)/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 - (935131412760109308018000000*sum((r3*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 - (35869453347570289778100000*sum((r3^2*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101 + (10124060799006000000*sum((r3^3*exp(r3*t))/(2*(169386*r3^3 + 3312090*r3^2 + 336237395*r3 + 891000000)), r3 in RootOf(s3^4 + (736020*s3^3)/28231 + (336237395*s3^2)/84693 + (594000000*s3)/28231 + 13810500000/28231, s3)))/422998807223231216101
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these built with the Symbolic Math Toolbox?

Try

```
t=0:0.01:10;
values_s = zs(t);
values_u = zu(t);
```

Comment: So did you try it? Did it work?
I'm not sure I understand what exactly you're trying to do...